# RPM failing to install on RHEL

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rhel-7

I am trying to install an RPM package on RHEL7. 
I am getting the following error;

```
Fri Aug 30 05:36:55 UTC 2019--> Start Installing downloaded package...
    file /etc/rc.d from install of abc.x86_64 conflicts with file from package chkconfig-1.7.4-1.el7.x86_64
    file /etc/rc.d/init.d from install of abc.x86_64 conflicts with file from package chkconfig-1.7.4-1.el7.x86_64
    file /etc/rc.d from install of abc.x86_64 conflicts with file from package initscripts-9.49.47-1.el7.x86_64
    file /etc/rc.d/init.d from install of abc.x86_64 conflicts with file from package initscripts-9.49.47-1.el7.x86_64
    file /usr/lib/systemd/system from install of abc.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-219-67.el7_7.1.x86_64
    file /usr/lib/systemd from install of abc.x86_64 conflicts with file from package systemd-219-67.el7_7.1.x86_64
```

What does this error really mean?
Does this mean that RPM abc is not allowed to make any changes to `/etc/rc.d` or `chkconfig-1.7.4-1.el7.x86_64` is a conflicting package?

Answer (score 0):

two `rpm` packages cannot provide the same file or directory. Therefore:

**DON'T**

this packages `/etc/rc.d` directory and content recursively.

```
%files
/etc/rc.d
```

**DO**

package only the files that really belong to your package.

```
%files
/etc/rc.d/init.d/*
```

Comment: I am adding a file `/etc/rc.d/init.d/my-script` thats it nothing else apart from that. According to you if some package already has created `/etc/rc.d` then how do I add my file in `/etc/rc.d/init.d`?

Comment: inside `%install` you must create the parent directories: `mkdir -p "${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/etc/rc.d/init.d/` etc. Then the files section as in my answer: `/etc/rc.d/init.d/my-script`